# Auto add query results as comments in Dbeaver

Tags: dbeaver

In Dbeaver, is there a way to get the query result into your SQL file?

This feature is handy when you have lots of queries and don't want to copy/paste their result one by one by hand.

An example of SQL file:

```
SELECT MAX(article) AS article FROM shop;
--+---------+
--| article |
--+---------+
--|       4 |
--+---------+

SELECT article,
SUBSTRING( MAX( CONCAT(LPAD(price,6,'0'),dealer) ), 7) AS dealer,
0.00+LEFT(      MAX( CONCAT(LPAD(price,6,'0'),dealer) ), 6) AS price
FROM   shop
GROUP BY article;

--+---------+--------+-------+
--| article | dealer | price |
--+---------+--------+-------+
--|    0001 | B      |  3.99 |
--|    0002 | A      | 10.99 |
--|    0003 | C      |  1.69 |
--|    0004 | D      | 19.95 |
--+---------+--------+-------+
```

Comment: Might figure out a way to save result to a table per query per datetime. So when run, what logic so something to insert to a new reporting data table something like `RunDateTime,Table, Result,Query`. Not sure if per table or per query and some query note value plus date and the result value could let you see the historical results. Might need to create a procedure but you determine if it'd be worth the time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53658882/how-do-i-create-a-sql-server-stored-procedure-with-dbeaver

Comment: seems like an interesting idea. Maybe someone with experience in making procedures could propose a suggestion.

Comment: 1. It seems like you're trying to create a "story". If so, use [Jupyter](https://www.google.com/search?q=jupyter+sql).
2. Your SQL [could be improved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group).

Comment: Can I create story in Dbeaver?